# Need Angular Material Dropdown Panel to have Down and Up Arrow buttons

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular 15`, `Angular Material 14` and `CSS`

I have almost finished my work in this sample..

I am using `-webkit-scrollbar` from this link - [Orangeable Scrollbars](https://orangeable.com/css/scrollbars)

The code used is as below...

```
<mat-select disableOptionCentering (selectionChange)="validateInputs(userForm)" formControlName="siteId" placeholder="Select Site ID" panelClass="custom-panel-siteId">

.custom-panel-siteId {
  margin: 40px 0px !important;
  min-width: 313px !important;
  margin-left: 17px !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242);
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211);
}
```

The output comes like this...

Just I need to add `Down` and `Up` arrows for the scrollbar.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Scrollbar]

Comment: Isn't `webkit-scrollbar-button` what you are looking for? There is docs for it on link you provided.

Comment: This is what I mean: https://orangeable.com/css/scrollbars#styling-scrollbar-buttons-with--webkit-scrollbar-button

Comment: Yes. When I use that, the rounded corners are going away for top right and bottom right of the dropdown panel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mattyork/pen/oGWOZY?editors=1100) I finally got the proper scrollbar for fixing this issue!

css

```
.custom-panel-siteId {
  margin: 40px 0px !important;
  min-width: 313px !important;
  margin-left: 17px !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  border-top: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  border-left: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #787878;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Buttons */
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 7px;
  background-position: center;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:disabled {
  /* Why is this not red??? */
  background-color: red;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:hover {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:active {
  background-color: #787878;
}

/* Up */
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23505050'><polygon points='50,30 100,80 0,80'/></svg>");
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:active {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23FFFFFF'><polygon points='50,30 100,80 0,80'/></svg>");
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #505050 transparent;
}

/* Down */
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23505050'><polygon points='0,15 100,15 50,75'/></svg>");
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:hover {
  border-color: #505050 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Left */
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23505050'><polygon points='15,50 75,100 75,0'/></svg>");
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent #505050 transparent transparent;
}

/* Right */
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23505050'><polygon points='15,0 15,100 75,50'/></svg>");
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #505050;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/j4fj2h-t3dauk?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html)

Comment: Could you please provide image for the background-image, instead of the URL?

Comment: @CPK_2011 You can take the contents from `<svg xmlns='` to the end and place in the assets folder in a file like `up.svg` and refer it, but even then you cannot avoid using `url` i think!

Comment: ok. Will do it.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<mat-select
        name="countryString"
        [(value)]="selectedCountry"
        placeholder="Country"
      >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let data of countries" [value]="data.full">{{
          data.full
        }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}

  countries: any = [
    {
      full: 'Great Britain',
      short: 'GB',
    },
    {
      full: 'United States',
      short: 'US',
    },
    {
      full: 'Canada',
      short: 'CA',
    },
    {
      full: 'asas',
      short: 'GB',
    },
    {
      full: 'United States',
      short: 'US',
    },
    {
      full: 'Canada',
      short: 'CA',
    },
  ];
  selectedCountry: string = 'GB';

  selectedCountryControl = new FormControl(this.selectedCountry);
}
```

Mat-select by default add up and down arrow

https://prnt.sc/QxbmuP1eTzj5